# Not all resolutions are listed

Tags: nvidia, display, display-resolution

My laptop is running Gnome 15.04 (Gnome version 3.14.2), my graphics card is NVidia GeForce 840M and I have the version 346.59 from nvidia-346 proprietary and tested drivers installed, however not all resolutions are listed, my screen supports 1920x1080 but the maximum listed in options is 1366x768, I've tried the folowing:

```
cvt 1920 1080
xrandr --newmode <modeline from the above command>
xrandr --addmode eDP1 1920x1080_60.00 #eDP1 is the used screen listed when I use xrandr -q
```

but I get the following error when executing the last line:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  37
  Current serial number in output stream:  38
```

Also worth mentioning is that 1920x1080 isn't displayed when using `xrandr`, only lower resolutions are. How can I get at least the 1920x1080 resolution to show up?

One more thing:

listed among the screens in xrandr is this:

```
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  1920x1080_60.00 (0x229)  173.0MHz
        h: width  1920 start 2048 end 2248 total 2576 skew    0 clock   67.2KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1120           clock   60.0Hz
```

I am using the drivers provided in `Additional Drivers`, also installing the nvidia-current from `ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates` did not help.

Comment: nope, I'm using the built in laptop monitor.

Comment: unfortunately there's no `monitors.xml` in my `~/.config/` folder... note that I only use one screen - namely the built in one.

Comment: yes, the monitors.xml doesn't exist and the resolutions are the same.

Comment: I don't think monitors.xml is the reason for this, also from what I can see the xml is used with 2+ monitors, while I have trouble with the built-in one(I don't have any other monitors attached to my laptop!)

Comment: I tried reinstalling the drivers, however the monitors.xml didn't appear

Comment: I don't have the option to detect displays

Comment: Apparently my system is using the integrated graphics as seen under Settings->Details, how can I switch it?